# Dynamically adding and removing TextFields to a ScrollView iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uitextfield

How to dynamically add and remove TextFields on button press (iPhone)? Also need to retrieve values from those TextFields. I could add textfields to scrollview, but while removing textfields by pressing delete button,that textfield is getting removed but have left the space there itself. For instance , if I delete second textfield, it gets deleted, but the below textfields are not moving up.

Comment: How about using UITableview and adding textFields in a cell , you can easialy add and remove cells in tableView

Comment: yes. that way it is easy. But i want to use scrollview.